# Accessing a User's system camera via Outlook-Addin

Tags: javascript, video-capture, outlook-web-addins, scriptlab

I'm aiming to develop an Outlook Add-in using Script Lab that allows users to record videos via email. My goal currently is to have the user click a button that will open their camera and display its output. When accessing the camera on a browser (i.e. Chrome), I can access the user's system camera via the following code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>video app</title>
  </head>



  <body>
    <!-- HTML DISPLAY CODE -->
    <video id="video" src=""></video>
    <button onclick="openCamera()">start recording</button>

    <!-- JS LOGIC -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
 function openCamera() {
    const constraints = {
        video: true,
        audio: false
      }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(mediaStream => {
        var video = document.querySelector("video");
        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.name + ":" + error.message);
      })
  
  }
```

When running this same script as an Outlook Add-in (on Script Lab as well as running a local npm dev-server), Requests for the camera go straight to the catch block without even prompting the user for permission. This is the output:

```
PermissionDeniedError: null
```

My Question is: How do I need to change the above code to allow camera functionality via an Outlook-Addin

[JSFiddle that illustrates my intended outcome:](https://jsfiddle.net/treycrossley/bdr5fvgx/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to a limitation of the underlying browser control that is being used to run the add-in. I believe Outlook is using Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge (NOT Chromium-based). You should not get this error when you have a configuration where Outlook uses the new Chromium-based Edge browser to run your add-in. Documentation on the configuration/browsers for Outlook add-ins can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).

Comment: Is it possible to use some form of polyfill to get this functionality on the IE-based version?